# resize matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, resize

i was using the function `"resizem"` to expand the size of my matrix, without erasing the data. recently, after using the function, it sends me an error that the function cannot use integers of type double. i have tried to use `abs().^2` on my matrix but it didn't work.

is there any other function that can do the same?

note: i need the data to not change, so if i have an matrix
 `A = [-1 0 2; 4 1 2]` i want it to become a 5x5 matrix like so:
 `A = [-1 -0.5 0 1 2; 4 2.5 1 1.5 2]`

Also, I have tried the function 'imresize', and gives me the same problem as the resizem. (I own both the tool box, and my matrix is in type double)

Answer (score 0):

If `A = [-1 0 2; 4 1 2]` you could do something like `A = [A, [1, 2; 1.5 2]]` to get `A = [-1 -0.5 0 1 2; 4 2.5 1 1.5 2]`.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to go for `imresize` (which is part of the `Image Processing Toolbox`). I never used those functions, but looking at the error you are receiving, which is related to variable types, the new option should provide more flexibility. In fact, while `resizem` returns double precision output, `imresize` returns an output of the same type as the input.

```
A = [-1 0 2; 4 1 2];
imresize(A,[2 5]);
```

The example shows how to use it. I also tested both outcomes:

```
A = [-1 0 2; 4 1 2];

A_imr = imresize(A,[2 5]);
A_rem = resizem(A,[2 5]);
```

This is the result for `imresize`:

```
A_imr:

-1,08000000000000   -0,720000000000000  -1,77635683940025e-15   1,29600000000000    2,16000000000000
 4,24000000000000     2,82400000000000       1,00000000000000   1,48000000000000    2,08000000000000
```

This is the result for `resizem`:

```
A_rem :

-1  -1  0   2   2
 4   4  1   2   2
```

For further tinkering, try to play with `scale` and `method` arguments. In `imresize`, for example, you need to specify the appropriate interpolation kernel to achive averaging.